# What are unmanaged objects?

Tags: c#

What are unmanaged objects? Can you please explain it in terms of the CLR? I learned on the internet that they say unmanaged objects don't run under the CLR environment. Can you please give me an example of unmanaged objects?

Comment: quite poor in english....:)sorry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any memory not managed by the CLR memory management (i.e. garbage collector) is unmanaged memory.

An OS file handle is one example of unmanaged memory (under .NET and windows).

> To properly dispose of unmanaged
>   resources, it is recommended that you
>   implement a public Dispose or Close
>   method that executes the necessary
>   cleanup code for the object. The
>   IDisposable interface provides the
>   Dispose method for resource classes
>   that implement the interface. Because
>   it is public, users of your
>   application can call the Dispose
>   method directly to free memory used by
>   unmanaged resources. When you properly
>   implement a Dispose method, the
>   Finalize method becomes a safeguard to
>   clean up resources in the event that
>   the Dispose method is not called.

Ref: [Cleaning Up Unmanaged Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/498928w2.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

In simple words, the unmanaged objects are the objects that aren't managed by the .Net framework.

Best example is the database connection or file operation are handled by the OS at the end and need to be liberated explicitly (File.Close() or Connection close) and won't be handled automatically by the Garbage collector.

Comment: IT means unmanaged resource arre stored in stack ..i am also confuse with stack and heap.. i learnt that object are stored in heap and GC takes care of those unused objects in heap and clean up

Comment: It isn't a heap and stack issue. It mean just that isn't the responsability of the .net Framework(and GC in this case) to handle its liberation from memory.

Answer (score 1):

```
I learned on the internet that they say unmanaged objects don't run under the CLR environment.
```

This is not right, the CLR is pretty much able to do everything whats possible within C. In C# you have got a keywoard called unsafe which allows you to access even pointers and pointer offsets. I have a project where I do heavy Interop with a game engine and the C wrapper is so small, because I can handle all the memory objects within the CLR/C#.

By *doesn't* run they probably wanted to make it explicitly clear that the unamanged objects are not handled by the virtual machine: you have to do the cleanup or create wrapper classes which do the clean up for you.

Answer (score 1):

VC++6.0 samples or many of activeX and COM objects your using everyday for your application or website are unmanaged, for example Excel VBA is unmanaged and too many other samples.